# Tmux over SSH in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell-script, tmux

I'm trying to write a script which spawns multiple long-running commands on both a remote and local machine. Currently, an example of my solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t user@1.2.3.4 tmux new -s remote -d "find / *"

tmux new -s local -d "find / *"
```

However, when these commands become more complex (long, chained commands with quotation marks in them, instead of just a single `find` command), it becomes messy to put them on a single line and escape all the nested quotation marks.

I have tried using SSH with a so called "here document", e.g.:

```
ssh -t user@1.2.3.4 << EOF
    tmux new -s remote -d "find / *"
EOF

tmux new -s local -d "find / *"
```

But this leads to either the error `not a terminal` with the -T or -t option for SSH, or to some very strange behavior when using the -tt option.

Any suggestions to optimize/dramatically alter my approach?

Comment: A here-document redirects stdin, which is not the same thing as providing a command on the ssh (and ultimately tmux) command line. Are these commands largely fixed, such that a remote script file (possibly with a small number of parameters) may be a workable approach?

Comment: Although these commands are mostly static, I'd like to maintain only 1 set of scripts instead of 2 (local + remote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to combine [this idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22682/how-to-launch-a-set-of-program-inside-tmux-or-gnome-terminal-within-a-script) with [this other idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934280/ssh-heredoc-bash-prompt) and get something like this to work:

```
CMDS=$(cat <<CMD
read -e -p "Enter the path to the find: " FILEPATH
echo \$FILEPATH
#find \$FILEPATH -name $FILENAME
#read -p done: 
CMD
) 

tmux new -s finder -n remote "ssh localhost -t '$CMDS'" \; \
        new-window -n local  "bash -c '$CMDS'" \; \
            attach \;
```

Bonus - both commands are running in parallel and in the same `tmux` session.

Some quoting and escaping issues may remain depending upon the complexity of the commands you want to execute.  Also note the `read -p done` or your commands will execute, terminate and the `tmux` will also terminate without you seeing the output.  Perhaps that's what you intended, and the use of `find` was merely for example.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I'll test it for my specific setup and report back.

Just a small note: my intention is to make the SSH session run tmux on the remote host, instead of a local tmux session running SSH as your code does. This allow me to easily reconnect if the network is disconnected at some point. But that just applies to my specific case.
And `find` was indeed just an example of a long running command.

Comment: Works like a charm!